# Python Regular expression to replace date with timezone

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have CSV file which contains various timezone dates, but before feeding those data to tests, I want to replace all the dates with unify value.

date column contains values like below,

`2019-01-01 00:00:00+05:30
2018-12-31 18:30:00+00
2018-02-02 00:00:00-04:00`

I want replace them like

`2019-01-01 00:00:00+00
2018-12-31 00:00:00+00
2018-02-02 00:00:00+00`

How do I write Regex to cover all possible timezones?

I wrote:

([0-9]){4}(-:?)([0-9]){2}(-:?)([0-9]){2} ([0-9]){2}:([0-9]){2}:([0-9]){2}(+-?)([0-9]){2}:([0-9]){2}

but it fails when it encounter `2018-12-31 18:30:00+00`, How can I handle this case?

Comment: Just trying to understand your question here - do you want to convert all timezones to UTC? or completely remove the timezones?

Comment: @verisimilitude Make them UTC

Comment: I don't understand the connection between the expected output and the input, but in any case, regex alone is not the right tool to be doing this.  You need a date/time API of some sort.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen why is an API needed?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I wan to feed those unify data to tests, so that I don't have to bother about different timezone which is any ways handled by Frontend, this is Backend side tests, to make tests simpler I want to unify them make them UTC using RegEx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to solve this problem is using **python datetime **(strp and strf)

If you want to solve it using regex then as per python doc https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html 
you can do something like this

```
def dashrepl(matchobj):
  return "{0} 00:00:00+00".format(matchobj.group(1))

import re
k="(\d{4}(-\d{2}){2})\s(\d{2}:?){3}.[\d:]+"
ab = re.sub(k, dashrepl, "2019-01-01 00:00:00+05:30")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this is the solution I wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

Tim Biegeleisen is very right, you should not be using regex for this, you should use a datetime API provided by Python. I have sourced my answer from an excellent post on this by jfs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/608170)

The below is for `Python 3.3+` (since you have tagged your question with `Python 3.0`

```
time_string = "2019-01-01 00:00:00+05:30"
# Parses a datetime instance from a string 
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_string,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')
# Changes the timezone to UTC by setting tzinfo
timestamp = dt.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).timestamp()
# Converts back to a datetime object
dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
# Formats and prints it out.
print(dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'))
```

For `Python versions < 3.3`, for an `aware datetime`

```
    time_string = "2019-01-01 00:00:00+05:30"
    # Parses a datetime instance from a string 
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_string,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')
    # Changes the timezone to UTC by setting tzinfo
    timestamp = (dt - datetime(1970,1,1, tzinfo=timezone.utc)) / timedelta(seconds=1)
    # Converts back to a datetime object
    dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
    # Formats and prints it out.
    print(dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'))
```

**Terminology**

> An aware object is used to represent a specific moment in time that is
>   not open to interpretation

For our case, timezone information is known.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use regex for this as it seems to be straight forward. You can use the below snippet

```
ts = ["2019-01-01 00:00:00+05:30", "2018-12-31 18:30:00+00", "2018-02-02 00:00:00-04:00"]
l = [x.split()[0] + " 00:00:00+00" for x in ts]
```

OR

```
l = [x[:11] + "00:00:00+00" for x in ts]
```

Comment: Could you please RegEx example because date column can also come with other string as this is a backend tests?

Comment: use this one r"^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}[+-]\d{2}$"